# Changing the default latex generate command in AucTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I downloaded AucTeX off of `M-x package-list-packages` and I've enabled AucTeX in my .emacs with

```lisp
(load "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86/tex-site.el" nil t t)
```

When I type `C-c C-c` I would like to by default generate a pdf with pdflatex instead of a dvi with latex. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```lisp
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)                ; PDF mode (rather than DVI-mode)
```

to your .emacs.

Comment: To do this on a per-file basis add to the end of the a latex file
    `%%%Local Variables:` newline  `%%% eval: (TeX-PDF-mode 1)` newline `%%%End:`